# Muxing in audio to gstreamer RTMP stream kills both video and Audio

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, wowza

I need some genius help here - I'm trying to set up a live stream for my upcoming wedding... and I have it ALMOST working - audio seems to be the problem.

This is my setup

- Raspberry Pi Model B+
- Logitech C920 (with onboard h264 encoding that I am utilising)
- on-camera (C920) microphone
- USB wifi to iPhone 4G connection
- gstreamer1.0
- Amazon EC2 Wowza RTMP server

I have it all set up, but as soon as I mux in the audio, the streams wont play by any player.

What Works:
 - my gstreamer pipeline WITHOUT the audio muxed in
 - Wowza receives a consistent stream, no failures
 - The various Flash players / iOS / Android and VLC all play back the video

What doesnt:
 - enabling audio in the mux (using the pipeline below)
 - BUT gstreamer doesnt complain
 - BUT Wowza receives a consistent stream, no failures
 - The various flash players fail to play both Audio and Video. some just display the first video frame
 - VLC plays 1 video frame, and about 100ms of audio, then stops

Ideally I'd like the muxed audio/video FLV stored on the SD card too in case the network goes down - but if the 'tee' needs to be sacrificed to make it work, so be it.

This is my current FAILING pipeline - I assume there's something really stupid in it because I know practically nothing about gstreamer.... The first frame loads in all the players (except iOS.. which never shows anything)

```
# set camera resolution to 720p, and the data format to H264 (alternatives are YUV and JPG)
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=1280,height=720,pixelformat=1
# set the frame rate
v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --set-parm=10

gst-launch-1.0 -v -e uvch264src initial-bitrate=300000 average-bitrate=300000 device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true src.vidsrc \
                ! queue \
                ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=10/1 \
                ! h264parse \
                ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux \
                ! queue \
                ! tee name=t \
                ! queue \
                ! filesink location=/home/pi/wedding.flv t. \
                ! queue \
                ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://wowzaserver/live/wedding live=1' >>/home/pi/wedding.log 2>&1
```

Some of the things I can't really afford to change at this late stage are the encapsulation (FLV) and wowza RTMP because I've built everything around that...

Please Help!! Thanks!

## UPDATE

Given that I am also saving the FLV file, I have found that if I use ffmpeg to send that FLV file (using audio copy, video copy) to the RTMP server, everything works (but obviously its not live)! So I am now starting to believe this is a problem with the way Gstreamer encapsulates RTMP - and by putting ffmpeg in the middle it fixes it... but it's not live of course.
Is it possible to pipe my output to ffmpeg and using ffmpeg's RTMP?

Answer (score 1):

Mux isn't fed by any audio source+encoder!
autoaudiosrc should work as source + some AAC encoder (voaacenc or faacenc).